# Caught Unxpected token... in promisifyCall(ctx, fn, ...args) while using maingun in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun, nodemailer

I was using Node mailer to send a mail in my application. Now I changed it into Mail-gun API. After the changes, I got the following error.

```
function promisifyCall (ctx, fn, ...args) {
                                 ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

How do I resolve it?

I'm using Node v6.8.1.

Comment: We can't guide you based on the information in your question, no, not if the `^^^` are pointing to the right place. There's no unexpected token **there** (I've checked, the space is just a space).

Comment: What version of `node` do you have?

Comment: I'm using the version V6.8.1 in node

Comment: The code quoted above does not have any syntax error (if we assume a closing `}`) in Node v6.8.1.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  It occurs in package level during run time. And I have no idea how ti fix it.

Comment: I edited the post to put the `^^^` in the correct place. It refers to the varargs ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by utilizing version, **0.7.11**, of Mailgun-js.